# Spark - How to add a StructField at the beginning of a StructType in scala

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I have a schema which is of type StructType:

```
val schema = getSchema();  // getSchema returns StructType
```

I created another field of type StructField:

```
StructField("NAME", StringType, false)
```

I know that I can call schema.add() method to add the NAME field to the end of the existing schema, but how do I add NAME to the beginning of the schema to make it the first column?  Thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can create an auxiliary `StructType` and then add your existing one to it:

```
val auxSchema=StructType(Array(StructField("NAME", StringType, false)))
StructType(auxSchema++schema)
```

Answer (score 1):

This will work.

```
 val schema = StructType(
      StructField("string_column", StringType, true) ::
        StructField("int_column", IntegerType, true) ::
        StructField("float_column", FloatType, true) ::
        StructField("_corrupt_record", StringType, true) :: Nil
    )

 val newschema = schema.add(StructField("new_column", StringType, true))
 println(newschema)
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, adding some explanation on how and why it solves it will improve the quality of your answer